# Incorrect Figure reference numbering and how to reference a figure that doesn't have a caption

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, minipage

I'm trying to put 4 figures together such that three left figures are subfigures and belong to Figure 1, and another stand alone figure as the right most figure.

I have two questions:

First, when I reference the figures in my text, the numbering starts for 0, whereas it should actually start from 1, how to make it start from 1?

Second, if I don't assign a caption to one of the subfigures, I can't reference them in text.

Following is my code and the image of the what I'm trying to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelsep=space,font=small}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure*}[t]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.75\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.29\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{wu8_wedges}
  \captionof{subfigure}{this is a caption}
  \label{fig:a}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.29\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{wu8_wedges}
  \label{fig:b}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.29\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{wu8_wedges}
  \label{fig:c}
\end{minipage}%
\caption{Fig 1 caption this is}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.23\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{wu8_wedges}
  \caption{Fig 2 caption this is $\beta$}
  \label{fig:nextfig}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}


Why is it Figure \ref{fig:a}, and how to make references to Figures \ref{fig:b} and \ref{fig:c} work. Reference to Figure \ref{fig:nextfig} works?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `subfigure` is a deprecated package. Please don't use it!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thanks yes I know. Unfortunately this is a collaborative project, and has many other figures in the doc which are using subfigure, changing them all will be very expensive, so that is the constraint.

Comment: That's not a good strategy for future. Loading `subfigure` will overrule `caption`'s setting for such floats

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, I see, thanks for adding that bit of info. I suppose the question then is, is this situation salvageable or do we need to change everything?

Comment: You might replace the `subfigure` command with a `subfigure` environment (from the `subcaption` package), using `regular expressions`  for ‘Search and Replace’ in your editor.

Comment: \label stores the value of the counter from  the  last \refstepcounter.  If you want to reference a subfigure without a caption, you will need to call \refstepcounter{subfigure}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As supplement to above comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[t]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.75\linewidth}\centering
\subfloat[\label{fig:a}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{wu8_wedges}}
\hfil
\subfloat[\label{fig:b}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{wu8_wedges}}
\hfil
\subfloat[\label{fig:c}]{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{wu8_wedges}}
    \caption{Figure 1 has three subfigures}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.23\textwidth}\centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{wu8_wedges}
  \caption{Figure 2 has only one image}
  \label{fig:2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

See references for figures \ref{fig:a}, \ref{fig:b} and \ref{fig:c} which are part of Figure \ref{fig:1} and for Figure \ref{fig:2}. References works!

\end{document}
```

[image]